# Terminal warning when opening a file in gedit

Tags: command-line

I am getting the following error when running this command line:

```
sudo /etc/ddclient.conf
```

I installed ddclient by :

```
sudo apt-get install ddclient
```

It does open the editor with the file in question, but what does the error mean?

```
** (gedit:4090): WARNING **: Couldn't connect to accessibility bus: Failed to connect to socket /tmp/dbus-cSWf9rWIYX: Connection refused
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a bug affecting Gnome software. See this link on launchpad:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/1061554
I get the exact same on both of my Ubuntu 12.10 machines from the command prompt but gedit then works as intended.
If you're having any difficulty editing the ddclient.conf file you could try nano which opens inside the terminal window, but otherwise I would ignore the warning message in this case.

Answer (score 18):

The shell command:

```
export NO_AT_BRIDGE=1
```

prior to launch will squelch this annoying message.

Comment: Here's the Redhat [bug](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=889690) for reference.

Comment: I wish this were the default mode. :)

Comment: no it doesn't. -